# Как сделать условия с добавлением set в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, set

```
respone = requests.post('https://example.server', json=params, headers=header, params=params)
        data = respone.json()
        campaign = data['rows'][0]['campaign']
        key = data['rows'][0]['key']
       
        dann = set() 
            if dan == {key}:
             chat_msgs.append(('', f'<center><h3>Нету новых данных </h3></center> '))
            else:
             chat_msgs.append(('', f'<center><h3>Новый данные {campaign} /h3></center> '))
             dan.add({sub_id})
        run_async(refresh_msg(campaign, msg_box))
```

Использую pywebio как сервер установил сет все старые должны добавляться там чтобы старые данные не отправлялись страницу
Запускаю такой код не работает условия (не добавляется в set key)

Answer (score 0):

```
dan = set() # Здесь вы создаете переменную с двумя буквами nn
if dan == {key}: # А работаете с переменной с одной буквой n
    chat_msgs.append(('', f'<center><h3>Нету новых данных </h3></center> '))
else:
    chat_msgs.append(('', f'<center><h3>Новый данные {campaign} /h3></center> '))
    #После срабатывание не добавляется key в сет дан   
    dan.add(key) # А работаете с переменной с одной буквой n
run_async(refresh_msg(campaign, msg_box))
```

Comment: Проверьте есть ли ключ в переменной key. И Вы знаете, что set хранит только уникальные данные? Если в set уже этот ключ присутствует тогда остальные добавляться не будут.

Comment: Все добавляется в коде нету ошибок когда я делаю вывожу print(dan) после условии добавляется key
А если до него не добавляется попробовал добавить метод update не получается

Comment: Когда у Вас в dan допустим два ключя `{'1', '2'} `и когда приходит ключ `'2'` Вы проверяете `if dan == {key}:` то-есть  получается `if  {'1', '2'} ==  {'2'} : -> False` и тогда вам нужно добавить  в `dan '2' `но в `dan` двойка уже есть потому она не добавится.

Comment: Понимаете не в этом дело 
dan = set() 
print(dan) # Тут отображается как set 
if dan == {key}: # А работаете с переменной с одной буквой n
    chat_msgs.append(('', f'<center><h3>Нету новых данных </h3></center> '))
else:
    chat_msgs.append(('', f'<center><h3>Новый данные {campaign} /h3></center> '))
    #После срабатывание не добавляется key в сет дан   
    dan.add(key)
print (dan) 
А тут уже добавляется key но условия не считает его